# can't disable alt+t with autohotkeys, alt & Tab works (gets disabled) but not alt+t

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

sorry I forgot to mention I am using Jeff Atwood's wasd 104-key code keyboard and "Mac Mode is set to on\
I am remote desktopping into my mac computer from windows:

I'm trying to disable the context switcher with autohotkeys using:

```
!t::return
```

I've also tried

```
LAlt & t::
```

neither work for some reason.
disabling t altogether works using:

```
t::return
```

and disabling alt+tab works using:

```
LAlt & Tab::rule here...
```

Comment: What's a `context switcher`? I've tried `!t::return` with another app and it worked.

Comment: the windows 7 app switcher, i disabled aero, using a default theme, ive disabled the desktop composition and aero feature in the advanced system properties visual performance settings.

Comment: it basically tabs through the open applications and switches them, when i press alt + t, but im trying to disable it

Comment: with aero turned off, it tabs through the applications on the windows taskbar

Comment: I don't see Alt-T used anywhere in Windows 7. Aren't you confusing `t` with `Tab`? Then you should use `!Tab::return`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am using Jeff Atwood's wasd 104-key code keyboard and "Mac Mode is set to on\

Comment: I am remote desktopping into my mac computer from windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934341/code-keyboard-dip-switch-set-to-mac-mode-using-chrome-remote-desktop-on-windows

Comment: also trying to disable alt completely doesn't work either

Comment: You still haven't explained how `t` is related to `tab`. Also delete the comments, they're duplicating the question now. And why is there a link to another question? As for disabling Alt: use both `LAlt::return` and `RAlt::return`.

Comment: Your remote desktop software probably implements it's hotkey on a lower level. What's the software you are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this and works ok.

```
!t::Send {}
```